# It works fine in local machine but in hosting site when post data it gives Token Mismatch-exception(VerifyCsrfToken)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, hosting, laravel-5.3, web-hosting

I hosted my Laravel project by copying project from my local machine. I have included { csrf_token } and also deleted token session files but still it is giving same error. Please somebody help me to solve this problem

```html
<form class="login-form" method="POST" role="form" action="{{url('/login') }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <div class="row margin">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
                <input class="validate" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" class="center-align"></label>
                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="row margin">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <label for="password"></label>
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">          
            <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12  login-text">
              <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember-me" />
              <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12" type="submit" >Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
              <p class="margin medium-small"><a href="{{ url('register')}}">Register Now</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
              <p class="margin right-align medium-small"><a href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot password</a></p>
            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
              <a class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook" href="{{ url('redirect/facebook')}}">
                                    Login with Facebook </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
              <a class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook" href="{{ url('redirect/google')}}" >
                              Login with Google</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: Can you post your form ? And did you change the middleware ?

Comment: No i didn't changed anything in middleware same thing works fine in my local machine.. Thank in advance @Alex

Comment: I couldn't able to post any data, project hosting fine

Comment: Are your sessions working properly? If your session resets on every request the token is invalid

Comment: @Björn how can i check that.. ?

Comment: Can you upload the code of the form here ?

Comment: @Björn you can check now.

Comment: Make a route `session/put` that puts some data in the session: `session(['test' => 'it's working']);`. And then make a route `session/get` that checks if its in the session correctly: `dump(session('test'));`

Comment: @Björn want me to give github link you can check whole project ?

Comment: @Björn   is it right ?                                                   
   `Route::get('/session/put',function(){
  session(['test' => 'its working']);
});
Route::get('/session/get',function(){
    dump(session('test')); 
});`

Comment: @Björn for '/session/put' response is nothing                                                                    for '/session/get' response is null

Comment: If the response of `/session/get` is null after you visited `session/put`, it seems like your sessions are not working. Is your `storage` folder writable by the webserver so laravel can save session files there?

Comment: @Björn `Storage` folder has all permissions

Comment: @Björn i tried these url in my local sever it works same as hosted server. Please help me your help is very much needed

Answer (score 0):

check your APP_URL in your config file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

make sure that is the same as your domain, also clear your cache in laravel

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
$exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
// return what you want
});
```

Comment: In local system it is working fine but in hosting site it is giving token mismatch exception

Comment: i know, do this on the new webhost, change http://localhost, to whatever your site name is, also clear the cache on the new webhost, as above

Comment: sorry buddy i will try it now.

Comment: have you looked at the html of the form to make sure it actually is generating the token?

Comment: yeah i checked in console it generating the token

Comment: _token:BfLe6gnaOniQg9HraAlekx2EkoVP92CDoANRLxT6